# How to loop through this trees? laravel php nested sets recursively (SAME MODEL)

Tags: php, laravel, nested, set

How can I loop through this tree node, in laravel??
It took me couple of days to get it to work but it doesn't!!
Here is the table structure:

```
id        parent_id        text;
1         0                parent;
2         1                child;
3         2                descendant;
4         0                parent;
```

`
And so on....

Here is the model relationship

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ContextMenuItem','parent_id')->where('parent_id',0);
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ContextMenuItem','parent_id');
}
```

Here is the function that I don't know how to use it to get the items recursively.

```
public static function getTree(string $id, array $tree = []): array
{
    $lowestLevel = ContextMenuItem::where('id', $id)->first();

    if (!$lowestLevel) {
        return $tree;
    }

    $tree[] = $lowestLevel->toArray();

    if ($lowestLevel->parent_id !== 0) {
        $tree = ContextMenuItem::getTree($lowestLevel->parent_id, $tree);
    }

    return $tree;

}
```

Comment: Are you going to build a tree in view ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to accomplish, how can I return this from the controller??

Comment: You should not build tree in controller. pass data, then create it in view using Blade

Comment: Can you provide an example? Using the above function??

Comment: I told you, Don't build tree in controller

Comment: OK, what modifications, should I make in the model, to make this function to work? So, when I'm in controller I can just retreive it like mode::getTree();

Comment: Oh God, my solution is to build the tree in view, Do you understand me ?

Comment: No problem, what can I do to make it work in the view?
Now It only returns for each row, how can I make it retrieve all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you my example of a working code on Articles. In App\Article.php

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class, 'master_id', 'id');
}
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'master_id', 'id');
}
```

The ArticleController.php

```
$articles = Article::where('master_id', 0)->orderBy(...)->paginate();
```

in the articles/index.blade.php

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    @include('articles.article_item_well', ['recursive' => true])
@endforeach
```

and articles/article_item_well.blade.php after handling the standard output

```
@if ($recursive && $article->children()->count() > 0)
<div class="panel-body">
    @foreach($article->children as $article)
        @include('articles.article_item_well')
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

The beauty of it is that you can call it recursive or not. It can handle an infinite number of children. In some cases, like search results, you rather don't have recursive results. Then of course, you drop the `where('master_id', 0)` in the search function results object and in the view `['recursive' => false]`.

**Addition:** I have admit that paginate() does take 15 top level records, but it can't control the number of children. In my case that's not a big deal. If that is important to you, I believe it can be done on database level. But unfortunately, I can't help you with that, neither on raw SQL nor eloquent. I've seen the SQL command once in an example, it's has a complexity above my knowledge of (My)SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then please make the answer the right answer. Happy I could help you out. It took me a while to figure this out myself at the time.

Comment: Done, thanks so much for your efforts.
Sorry this is my first ever stackoverflow question..
But ever wondered, would this replace the logic of nested sets in java?
(Closure table and adjacency list ....)
??

Comment: I have no experience with Java. (edit) Thank you, the page didn't show your choice. I had to refresh to see the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

I think the primary problem lies within your relationship definition:

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ContextMenuItem','parent_id')->where('parent_id',0);
}
```

The `->where('parent_id', 0)` will cause an issue for children with a depth of higher than 1, because only the children of the root parent have a parent with `parent_id = 0`. I haven't worked with recursive relationships yet, but from your code, I would say remove the `where` and you are good to go.

After that you should be able to load all children with `with('children')` in the query.

Comment: Now I understand it a bit more, but how can I get the tree from the mode?

Comment: To get an idea how the result will look like, simply do something like `dd(Model::with('children')->find($id)->toJson())` in your controller. Obviously replace `Model` and `$id` with something that suits you. If you can give us an example of what your tree needs to look like, maybe we can assist with it.

Comment: Where do you have troubles?

Comment: Well, main problem was between my chair and my screen. :D :D 
I solved the problem.
Thank you so much